# ¿Puedo usar Netbeans 8 con Java 9?

Tags: netbeans-8.2, java-9

Tengo **Netbeans 8.2** en Windows y acabo de instalar **JDK** y **JRE** **9.04**. 
Ahora Netbeans no arranca. Aparece la ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

seguida de:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si le doy al botón "Si".

Por lo que estuve viendo ***Netbeans 8.2*** no funciona con Java 9.
He probado a bajar el instalador de una versión en desarrollo de Netbeans (netbeans-trunk-nightly-201803030002-javase-windows), pero me lanza la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer funciona Netbeans y si es así, me dará problemas con las características que se incorporan en Java 9?

Comment: Fijate que en la variables de entorno este apuntado a la capeta donde tengas instalado el sdk. Si no recuerdo mal la variable se llama JAVA_HOME.
Puede que sea eso. Un saludo.

Comment: TIenes un jdkhome definido para netbeans que no apunta al java9 que mencionas.

Comment: Lo otro: para editar la ruta que usa netbeans para buscar el jdk, edita el archivo `netbeans.conf` en la carpeta `etc` de la instalación de NetBeans y busca/añade el valor `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_xyz"`

Answer (score 2):

Debes descargar la [versión de desarrollo](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/), es allí donde lo he probado, pero ojo, **no desinstalar** tu versión de Java 8, pues mientras no soporte completamente Java 9 para funcionar necesita del **rt** para levantar el netbeans.

Más información acerca del soporte a Java 9 [aquí](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support).

el 15 de Febrero liberaron ya la versión beta de netbeans 10 ya por parte de Apache, puedes descargarlo [aquí](http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0-beta/), y leer más al respecto [aquí](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3257564/java/whats-new-in-apaches-netbeans-ide-for-java.html).

Te agrego un [tutorial de Java 9](http://javapro.org/blog/java-9-hello-world/) que creé en 2016, algunas cosas seguramente han cambiado desde entonces, hace dos meses lo trabajé con [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) que de momento es la opción de compilación más estable junto con [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle).

**Edición:**

[Esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218930/c%C3%B3mo-correr-apache-netbeans-9-cannot-find-java-1-8-or-higher) es la forma de correr el nuevo apache netbeans si tienes Java 11