# ¿Cómo correr apache netbeans 9? Cannot find Java 1.8 or higher

Tags: netbeans, windows10, netbeans-9

¡Hola mundo!
Me bajé el apache netbeans de la página de [siempre](https://netbeans.org/), seleccioné la opción que dice

> Binaries: incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip

Lo descomprimí en la carpeta `C:\Ambiente` y busqué el ejecutable de 64 bits que hallé en la carpeta `C:\Ambiente\netbeans\bin` pero al darle doble click me muestra este error en inglés:

[image: mensaje de error al dar doble click: Cannot find Java 1.8 or higher]

Lo cual es extraño porque tengo Java instalado y configurado. Al correr un cmd y poner le comando `java -version` obtengo

> java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

¿Existe alguna configuración necesaria para poderlo correr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haciendo una búqueda hallé en el sitio en inglés [el procedimiento para solucionarlo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052219/cannot-find-java-please-use-the-jdkhome-switch).

Se trata de buscar en la carpeta `etc` que en mi caso hallé en `C:\Ambiente\netbeans\etc` y allí buscar la línea comentada que dice `netbeans_jdkhome=` y hacer que apunte a la rut del JDK, en mi caso quedó así:

```
# Default location of JDK:
# (set by installer or commented out if launcher should decide)
#
# It can be overridden on command line by using --jdkhome <dir>
# Be careful when changing jdkhome.
# There are two NetBeans launchers for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and
# installer points to one of those in the NetBeans application shortcut 
# based on the Java version selected at installation time.
#
netbeans_jdkhome="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.1"
```

Espero le sirva a alguien que tuviera el mismo problema.

Comment: excelente aporte, solo recuerda que en cuanto te sea posible aceptes tu respuesta para que el resto sepamos que esto es la solución

Comment: Sí amigo, eso será en unos dos días que se me habilite la opción